# ReactJS Call parent method with a button in child that uses parent values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, parent-child

I have a following problem:

I got a card element that i render in my parent component. To render it i use the following code:

PARENT:

```
import WordCard from "./subComponents/card"

class Home extends Component {

state = {

words:['id1','id2','id3','id4']

}

parentMethod(data){
//my actual code here
//Right now just trying to at least print the 'uid' so:
     console.log(data)
}
...
render(){
...
return(...
  {this.state.words.map(i =>
   <WordCard 
     parentMethod={this.parentMethod} 
     uid = {i['_id']}
   />
  )}
)}
```

CHILD:
Here i have a card with a 'like' button.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Card } from 'react-bootstrap'

...

const cards = (props) => {

return (
...

<Card>
<Button onClick={() => this.props.parentMethod(this.props.uid)}  >

/Card>


...
}

export default cards;
```

I am trying to print a unique id of every 'like' button that is generated with map function on the parent side. But i can not wrap my head around it. It gives me : Cannot read property 'props' of undefined every time.

Could you please help me out.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the child component class-based? You are using `this.props` for the method but `props` for `id`.

Comment: yes it is class based. I will add now

Comment: First of all, it should be `this props.uid` in the child. As its current shape, your code should work since you are only logging the data in the callback. But, if you use `this` there then you should bind your function it or make it an arrow one.

Comment: where this Child Component used in Home? You seems to pass props to WordCard but u r wishing to accept it in Child component, need more clearer details

Comment: Can we see your whole components, please? @RonitMukherjee pointed out that you are using `WordCard` in the parent but in your question, there is `Child` component. So, just provide both components with much more code.

Comment: Sorry, but still not enough to dig the error. Your code should work as in its current shape. We really need to see your actual code.

Comment: I still get the same error. I added pretty much everything related to the problem. I have a card component Card which i export to Home as WordCard. Home has a state with an array of ids . Im map over that array and render a card for each element there. I am trying to pass the each id to the card so that when i click the 'like' button which is created inside of a card component, i get that id printed.

Comment: I understand you but unfortunately, you didn't add pretty much everything about the problem :) [Your code and working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-field-ikkl6?file=/src/App.js) As you can see, your simple code works without error.

Comment: I figured it out finally thanks to your sandbox example. I will close the question.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for **"Can't read Props of Undefined"** is that the function when goes inside the child component and being called by the event handler then the function is **not called in the context of Home/Child/WordCard or any component in which the function is defined**.

**Before passing it to the event try binding the function to the context you want it to be called**.

**For a solution in Home Component**

```
Class Home{
 constructor(){
   //Way 1
   this.methodName = this.methodName.bind(this);
 }
 ....
 methodName(){
   //Using this inside
   console.log(this.someThing); //Eg. this.state, this.props
 }

 //Way 2
 methodName = methodName.bind(this);
}
```

*Use any of the Way but not both together.*

Comment: Binding is not needed here. OP just uses the callback to log the data. No `this` context there.

Comment: I guess she has provided incomplete code, but the error she mentioned seems related to the context, and not able to access props.

Comment: "I am trying to print a unique id of every 'like' button"... so clearly stated that code just prints/logs the data. I know the error sounds related to `this` context but how can we be sure?

Comment: I just edited the code sample. Hopefully, this is enough. Please help